# I need a simple way to compile C++ code on a Mac intel, for the purpose of learning C++. I

Tags: c++, macos, compiler-construction

I have a text book already and need a painless!! way to write and test the code

Answer (score 6):

Your OSX DVD will have a "SDK", or Software Development Kit. Install that, and it will provide XCode and GCC, which are tools to compile with.

Comment: …at connect.apple.com. You need to sign up for a free account to download Xcode, but it will probably be a newer version than on your system install disc.

Answer (score 3):

Since this guy is just starting out...

Bok, you want to run "**g++**", or /usr/bin/g++, on your program source file in a terminal window.  (Things will go easier if your source file ends in .cc, .cxx, or .cpp.)

E.g.:        *g++ foo.cc -o foo -Wall*

**g++** is installed when you install the OSX SDK from the disks that came with your computer...  (Apple's *Software Development Kit* is not installed by default.  But it is included, for free, with every Apple computer sold.)

Answer (score 2):

You can create "Command Line Utility" apps in C++ using XCode (Project -> New)

Answer (score 1):

If you install Xcode from the DVD supplied with your mac Gcc and friends will wind up in your path.  You can use them from the command-line just as you would on any other (Unix-y) OS that supports Gcc.

Vim is pre-installed on the Mac and with a bit of tweaking in ~/.vimrc you can edit C++ code there.

You're not tied to using Xcode if you find it painful.

Answer (score 0):

[XCode](http://developer.apple.com/TOOLS/xcode/) or [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) will nicely for you I think.

Answer (score 0):

If, for some reason, you don't want to use Xcode, you could install [fink](http://www.finkproject.org/) , then do a

```
fink install g++ make
```

which will give you the basics of a unix command line build environment (like most tutorials assume you have). I think you need to install the stuff from the developers DVD too, so you should really consider just using Xcode.

You might also want to

```
fink install emacs22-carbon
```

but that depends on your choice of editor. You probably need to install a few libraries and such as you go along.